# What am I doing wrong here? parse_item_page is not working for me

Tags: python, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from ..items import dealItem

class FarmtoolsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'farmtools'
    allowed_domains = ['www.deal.ie']
    start_urls = ['https://www.deal.ie/all?source=private&sort=publishdate%20desc']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = dealItem()
        rows = response.xpath('//ul[@class="card-collection"]/li')

        for row in rows:
            link = row.xpath('.//a/@href').get() #this is the full link.
            link_split = link.split('/')[-1] #this splits the url link th first time.
            linkid = link_split.split('?')[0] #this splits it the second time.
            title = row.xpath('.//div[1]/p[@class="card__body-title"]/text()').get()
            county = row.xpath('.//a/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul[@class="card__body-keyinfo"]/li[contains(text(),"min")]/following-sibling::node()/text()').get()
            price = row.xpath('.//p[@class="card__price"]/span[1]/text()').get()
            subcat = row.xpath('.//a/div/div[2]/div[1]/p[2]/text()[2]').get()
            zero = row.xpath('.//a/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul[@class="card__body-keyinfo"]/li[contains(text(),"min")]/text()').get()
            if zero == '0 min':

                items['linkid'] = linkid
                items['title'] = title
                items['county'] =  county
                items['price'] = price
                items['subcat'] = subcat
                items['zero'] = zero
                items['link'] = link



                yield response.follow(url=link,
                callback=self.parse_item_page,
                cb_kwargs={link: items})

    def parse_item_page(self, response, link):
        items = DonedealItem()

        rows = response.xpath('//html/body/main/div/div[1]/div')
        for row in rows:
            views = row.xpath('.//div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/span[2]/text()').get()
            seller_id = row.xpath('.//div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a/@href').get()
            seller_ads = row.xpath('.//div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/dl[3]/dd/text()').get()
            lifetime_ads = row.xpath('//div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/dl[4]/dd/text()').get()

            items['views'] = views
            items['seller_id'] = seller_id
            items['seller_ads'] = seller_ads
            items['lifetime_ads'] = lifetime_ad

        items['views'] = views

        yield{
            items
            }
```

The first parse method ran fine, but I'm not sure if I've written the second parse method out correctly.

Part of the first parse method scrapes specific links that I want to follow so I can scrape additional data from them.

What I want to achieve is to scrape the links that I got from the first parse method and get other item values from them and then add them all together as items.

I also have added `items = DonedealItem()` to both, but I'm not sure this is correct.

When I run it now I get: File "/home/william/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw) TypeError: parse_item_page() got an unexpected keyword argument 'donedeal.ie/cars-for-sale/e39-520i-for-breaking-also-have-lsd/…' . I get one of those for every link that is scraped. What I want to do is add more info like "seller id", "views" etc. to the info I scraped from the first parse method. Hope this helps

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Hi @billiam, what isn't working? Is an error ocurring? If not, what is the outcome you are getting right now and **what is the outcome you were expecting**? Please have a read on [how to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) It's very unclear to me how you want your items to work, as you are overwritting the data inside them.

Comment: Hi  renatodvc , sorry if I'm not being clear.

Comment: When I run it now I get:    File "/home/william/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
TypeError: parse_item_page() got an unexpected keyword argument 'https://www.donedeal.ie/cars-for-sale/e39-520i-for-breaking-also-have-lsd/25359548' . I get one of those for every link that is scraped. What I want to do is add more info like "seller id", "views" etc. to the info I scraped from the first parse method. Hope this helps

Comment: Hi there, could you post the content of your comment above into your question. That means all the information is in the one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can spot some issues with your code, including the cause of the error you mentioned in the comments, but **an issue will remain, as I don't fully understand the data structure you want scraped.**

- In your `parse` method you instantiate an `DonedealItem()` object in the `items` var. Then you **try** to send it as a callback argument (cb_kwargs) to the callback function (`parse_item_page`).

  ```
        ...
        yield response.follow(url=link,
            callback=self.parse_item_page,
            cb_kwargs={link: items})

   def parse_item_page(self, response, link):
       ...
  ```

The problem here is that `link` is a variable with an unpredictable value (as you set it to be a url) , it needs to be a string with the same value you defined in the callback function. So this should solve the error:

```
        yield response.follow(url=link,
            callback=self.parse_item_page,
            cb_kwargs={'link': items})
```

---

- However, your `parse_item_page` method isn't using `link` for anything. Instead it  instantiate a new `DonedealItem()`, populate it with the data parsed into this method and then yields it. The data received as the `link` parameter is left unused. If you want to **INCREMENT** the data your first `parse` method sent you, you need to use it:

  ```
    def parse_item_page(self, response, link):
        items = link # Your link param already receives an DonedealItem instance.
  ```

---

- This is a tip: there is no need for these curly braces:

  ```
   yield{
       items
       }
  ```

Use `yield items` instead

---

**The problem that will remain:**

- You can think of your `DonedealItem` as a dict, what your code is doing is instanting the item first then running a for loop and in each iteration of this loop overwriting the data inside your item. I believe you should instantiate your item inside the for loop, but I can't be sure, as I don't know what is the expected outcome nor how is `DonedealItem` defined. Even then, this would still cause an issue in the second parsing method, as it receives one item, and iterates again. Maybe you need to use lists.

Comment: Thanks renatodvc. Would it help if I pasted the items.py file here as well?

Comment: I think you should implement the changes I mentioned first, and see if everything is running. Next you should **check the scraped data**, you will probably be able to figure it out the logic by yourself, as you know best what you want. If you still need any help, please open a new question, and remember to include all the related data (don't forget to check the link I sent you in the comments). Finally, if my answer solved the issue that led you to open the question please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks renatodvc